# DbContext SaveChanges unpredictable

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a problem with DbContext SaveChanges() method, it sometime saves and sometimes doesn't.
In my WinForm application I have 12 numericUpDown controls which are representing values of 12 month back.

numericUpDown names are stored in List of string :

```
List<string> controlNames = new List<string>();

controlNames.Add("firstMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("secondMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("thirdMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("fourthMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("fifthMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("sixthMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("seventhMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("eighthMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("ninthMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("tenthMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("eleventhMonthNumericUpDown");
controlNames.Add("twelfthMonthNumericUpDown");
```

In form constructor I'm binding this controls to the CalculatedSalary property of Payment objects from my DbContext:

```
DateTime loopDate = new DateTime();

for (int monthBack = 1; monthBack <= 12; monthBack++)
{
    //BINDING PREVIOUS PAYMENTS SALARY
    loopDate = currentPayment.Month.AddMonths(-monthBack);

    NumericUpDown loopNumericUpDown = this.Controls.Find(controlNames[monthBack-1], true).First() as NumericUpDown;

    Payment loopMonthPayment = payment.Person.Payments.Where(p=>p.Month.Year == loopDate.Year && p.Month.Month == loopDate.Month).FirstOrDefault();

    if (loopMonthPayment == null)
    {
        //PERSON'S PAYMENT FOR THAT MONTH WAS NOT CREATED BEFORE
        loopMonthPayment = new Payment(loopDate);                        
        payment.Person.Payments.Add(loopMonthPayment);
    }                    

    //BIND PERSON'S PAYMENT FOR LOOPED MONTH TO LOOPED NUMERICUPDOWN CONTROL
    loopNumericUpDown.DataBindings.Add("Value", loopMonthPayment, "CalculatedSalary");
}
```

on save button click :

```
 Form1.entities.SaveChanges();
```

After changing values for all 12 month in numericUpDown, I press save button and check values in Database, but got a really strange result: they are always different means some Payments are changed and some are not, but the last one with the lowest date always changes...

Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you posted the code where you "change payments"? I did not find that part.

Comment: It sounds like a XAML binding problem. Show the XAML of the hpdowns, one where it works and one where it doesn't.

Comment: @simonatrcl It's Winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinForms default behaviour for data binding is to update the bound object's properties when the control's `Validate` method is called. There are some situations where it is called automatically, which explains why you do see some of the updates, but a click on a button is not one of those situations.

Most likely, updating the bound object's properties whenever the control's edit value changes would be more suited to your needs. To make that work, use an overload of `DataBindings.Add` that allows you to specify the `DataSourceUpdateMode`, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and make sure to pass [`DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).